# PDO in PDO search not display all results

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have pretty simple fucntion ( basicly doing same thing all the time ), which try to get data from 3 tables at once and then display it in on site. Problem is  that last PDO connect on database make problems with results.

Detail descriptions:
If i use code like this (last connect is commented , its on table axnmrs_positions) it display all resutls and all data for 1 VIN (ofc without data from commmented table) how it should. But if i uncomment it, it display just single result, and i have no idea WHY. Problem is somewhere between that few commented lines and the end but cant find where.

What i need:
Let code find and display all results from all 3 tables, not just for single one

p.s. I know CODE is terrrible but its my start of PHP OOP / PDO and so on, so please respect i am learning :)

My code:

```
     public function fetchByVinAxnmrss($con) {
         $success = false;
         //$this->vin = "KMHLC81UACU021096";
         if($this->vin){
         try{
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM axnmrs_cases WHERE vin = :vin LIMIT 30";
            $stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
            $stmt->bindValue( "vin", $this->vin, PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt->execute();
                while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){
                    echo"<tr>";
                    echo  "<td class='number'>".$row['claimnumber']."</td>";
                    // Remove time from date
                    $date = substr($row['date_created'], 0, -9); 
                    echo  "<td class='city'>".$date."</td>"; 
                    //echo  "<td class='street'>Axnmrs</td>";
                    // Which Insurer work on it? 
                    switch ($row['insurer_memberid']) {
                        case "MM-O-37C4CD31-1":
                            echo  "<td class='case'>Allianz</td>";
                            break;
                        case "MM-O-679147C3":
                            echo "<td class='case'>Česká pojišťovna</td>";
                            break; 
                        case "MM-O-8484AD31-2":
                            echo "<td class='case'>Česká pojišťovna</td>";
                            break; 
                        case "MM-O-8484AD31":
                            echo "<td class='case'>Česká pojišťovna</td>";
                            break; 
                        case "MM-O-78EFD7AF":
                            echo "<td class='case'>Česká pojišťovna</td>";
                            break; 
                        case "MM-O-26D1C0EF":
                            echo "<td class='case'>Servisní pojišťovna</td>";
                            break;  
                        case "MM-O-D45A6DEF":
                            echo "<td class='case'>Triglav Pojišťovna</td>";
                            break;  
                        case "MM-O-26D1C0EF":
                            echo "<td class='case'>Servisní pojišťovna</td>";
                            break;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
                        default:
                            echo "<td class='case'>Servis</td>";                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                    } 

                    echo  "<td class='country'>".$row['country']."</td>";
                    echo  "<td class='action'><button class='btn btn-flat btn-view'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open' title='Show Detail'></span></button></td>";                    
                    echo"</tr>";

                  echo"<tr class='detail'>";
                   echo"<td colspan='6'>";
                      echo "<div class='case-detail row'>";  
                      echo  "<div class='col-xs-6 col-md-3'>";      
                          echo"<dl>";
                          // What parts are used
                          echo  "<dt>Použité náhradní díly</dt>";
                          if ($row['part_supplier']=1){
                          echo  "<dd>Originální</dd>";}
                          else{
                          echo  "<dd>Alternativní</dd>";}

                          echo  "<dt>Datum vytvoření případu</dt>";
                          echo  "<dd>".$row['date_created']."</dd>";

                          echo  "<dt>SPZ</dt>";
                          echo  "<dd>".$row['platenumber']."</dd>";

                          echo  "<dt>Totální škoda</dt>";
                          if (empty($row['totalloss'])){
                          echo $row['totalloss'];    
                          echo  "<dd>Ne</dd>";}
                          else{
                          echo  "<dd>Ano</dd>";}                            

                          echo  "<dt>VIN</dt>";
                          echo  "<dd>".$row['vin']."</dd>";   

                          $this->manufacturer_code = $row['lastcalc_manufacturer_code'];
                          $this->main_type = $row['lastcalc_model_code'];
                          $this->subtype_code = $row['lastcalc_submodel_code'];  

                          echo  "<dt>Druh vozidla</dt>";
                          echo  "<dd>".$this->getCarType()."</dd>";                          

                          echo"</dl>";
                        echo"</div>";
                        // DRUHY STLPEC
                        echo"<div class='col-xs-6 col-md-3'>";
                          echo"<dl>";

                          echo  "<dt>Identifikace vozidla pomocí AudaVIN</dt>";
                          if (isset($row['audavin_trigged'])){
                          echo  "<dd>Ano</dd>";}
                          else{
                          echo  "<dd>Ne</dd>";}                          
                          // DATUM NEHODY
                          echo  "<dt>Datum nehody</dt>";
                          if ($row['accident_date'] == "0000-00-00 00:00:00"){
                              echo "<dd>Neni k dispozici</dd>";
                          }
                          else{
                          echo  "<dd>".$row['accident_date']."</dd>";
                          }
                          // DATUM REGISTRACE VOZIDLA
                          echo  "<dt>Datum registrace vozidla</dt>";
                          if ($row['registration_date'] == "0000-00-00 00:00:00"){
                              echo "<dd>Neni k dispozici</dd>";
                          }
                          else{
                          echo  "<dd>".substr($row['registration_date'], 0, 10)."</dd>"; 
                          }

                     $this->case = $row['case_id'];
                     try{
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM axnmrs_calculations WHERE case_id = :case LIMIT 1";
                        $stmt_calculations = $con->prepare( $sql );
                        $stmt_calculations->bindValue( "case", $this->case, PDO::PARAM_STR );
                        $stmt_calculations->execute();                   
                        while ($row = $stmt_calculations->fetch()){

                          $this->calculationid = $row['calculation_id'];

                          echo  "<dt>Cena náhradních dílů</dt>";
                          echo  "<dd>".$row['spareparts']."</dd>";

                          echo  "<dt>Celkové náklady</dt>";
                          echo  "<dd>".$row['totalcosts']."</dd>";                           
                          echo"</dl>";
                        echo"</div>"; 

                        echo"<div class='col-xs-6 col-md-3'>";
                          echo"<dl>";
                          echo  "<dt>Celkový počet hodin práce</dt>";
                          echo  "<dd>".$row['laborhours']."</dd>";

                          echo  "<dt>Datum vytvoření kalkulace</dt>";
                          echo  "<dd>".substr($row['calculationdate'], 0, 17)."</dd>";      // ODSTRANIT 0000

                          echo  "<dt>Lakovací materiál</dt>";
                          echo  "<dd>".$row['paintmaterial']."</dd>";

                          echo  "<dt>Náklady na práci</dt>";
                          echo  "<dd>".$row['laborcosts']."</dd>";

                          echo  "<dt>Náklady na lakování</dt>";
                          echo  "<dd>".$row['paintlabor']."</dd>";                                                    

                          echo  "<dt>Měna</dt>";
                          echo  "<dd>".$row['currency']."</dd>";  
                          echo"</dl>";
                        echo"</div>";                                                                             
                          }

                            }catch(PDOExeption $e){
                            echo $e->getMessage();
                            echo $con->errorInfo();
                            } 

                        echo"<div class='col-xs-6 col-md-3'>";
                          echo"<dl>";
                          echo  "<dt>Seznam použitých náhradních dílů </dt>";
                        //$this->calculationid = $row['calculation_id'];

                        try{
                            echo "NECO";
                        /*
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM axnmrs_positions WHERE calculation_id = :calculationid LIMIT 60";
                        $stmt_position = $con->prepare( $sql );       
                        $stmt_position->bindValue( "calculationid", $this->calculationid, PDO::PARAM_STR );
                        $stmt_position->execute();
                        while ($row = $stmt_position->fetch()){ 
                        echo  "<dd>".$row['text']."</dd>";  
                            }
                        */    
                        }catch(PDOExeption $e){
                        echo $e->getMessage();
                        echo $con->errorInfo();
                            } 
                        /*    
                          echo"</dl>";
                        echo"</div>"; 

                return $success;  
                */
                echo"</div>";
                echo "</td>" ;
                echo "</tr>";
                }
                }catch(PDOExeption $e){
                echo $e->getMessage();
                echo $con->errorInfo();
                }
                return $success;
             }             
         }  




     public function getCarType() {
         /*
         $this->manufacturer_code = "00";
         $this->main_type = "03";
         $this->subtype_code = "05";
          */
         $success = false;
         try{
            $con = new PDO( DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS ); 
            $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM car_type WHERE manufacturer_code = :manufacturer_code AND main_type = :main_type AND subtype_code = :subtype_code LIMIT 1";
            $stmt_car = $con->prepare( $sql );
            $stmt_car->bindValue( "manufacturer_code", $this->manufacturer_code, PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt_car->bindValue( "main_type", $this->main_type, PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt_car->bindValue( "subtype_code", $this->subtype_code, PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt_car->execute();
                while ($row = $stmt_car->fetch()){
                    echo $row['manufacturer'];
                    echo "&nbsp;";
                    echo $row['model'];
                    echo "&nbsp;";
                    echo $row['submodel'];
                }
                }catch(PDOExeption $e){
                echo $e->getMessage();
                echo $con->errorInfo();
                }

             return $success; 
         }               
               echo  "<dd>Ano</dd>";}
                          else{
                          echo  "<dd>Ne</dd>";}                          
                          // DATUM NEHODY
                          echo  "<dt>Datum nehody</dt>";
                          if ($row['accident_date'] == "0000-00-00 00:00:00"){
                              echo "<dd>Neni k dispozici</dd>";
                          }
                          else{
                          echo  "<dd>".$row['accident_date']."</dd>";
                          }
                          // DATUM REGISTRACE VOZIDLA
                          echo  "<dt>Datum registrace vozidla</dt>";
                          if ($row['registration_date'] == "0000-00-00 00:00:00"){
                              echo "<dd>Neni k dispozici</dd>";
                          }
                          else{
                          echo  "<dd>".substr($row['registration_date'], 0, 10)."</dd>"; 
                          }

                     $this->case = $row['case_id'];
                     try{
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM axnmrs_calculations WHERE case_id = :case LIMIT 1";
                        $stmt_calculations = $con->prepare( $sql );
                        $stmt_calculations->bindValue( "case", $this->case, PDO::PARAM_STR );
                        $stmt_calculations->execute();                   
                        while ($row = $stmt_calculations->fetch()){

                          $this->calculationid = $row['calculation_id'];

                          echo  "<dt>Cena náhradních dílů</dt>";
                          echo  "<dd>".$row['spareparts']."</dd>";

                          echo  "<dt>Celkové náklady</dt>";
                          echo  "<dd>".$row['totalcosts']."</dd>";                           
                          echo"</dl>";
                        echo"</div>"; 

                        echo"<div class='col-xs-6 col-md-3'>";
                          echo"<dl>";
                          echo  "<dt>Celkový počet hodin práce</dt>";
                          echo  "<dd>".$row['laborhours']."</dd>";

                          echo  "<dt>Datum vytvoření kalkulace</dt>";
                          echo  "<dd>".substr($row['calculationdate'], 0, 17)."</dd>";      // ODSTRANIT 0000

                          echo  "<dt>Lakovací materiál</dt>";
                          echo  "<dd>".$row['paintmaterial']."</dd>";

                          echo  "<dt>Náklady na práci</dt>";
                          echo  "<dd>".$row['laborcosts']."</dd>";

                          echo  "<dt>Náklady na lakování</dt>";
                          echo  "<dd>".$row['paintlabor']."</dd>";                                                    

                          echo  "<dt>Měna</dt>";
                          echo  "<dd>".$row['currency']."</dd>";  
                          echo"</dl>";
                        echo"</div>";                                                                             
                          }

                            }catch(PDOExeption $e){
                            echo $e->getMessage();
                            echo $con->errorInfo();
                            } 

                        echo"<div class='col-xs-6 col-md-3'>";
                          echo"<dl>";
                          echo  "<dt>Seznam použitých náhradních dílů </dt>";
                        //$this->calculationid = $row['calculation_id'];

                        try{
                            echo "NECO";                        
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM axnmrs_positions WHERE calculation_id = :calculationid LIMIT 60";
                        $stmt_position = $con->prepare( $sql );
                        /*
                        $stmt_position->bindValue( "calculationid", $this->calculationid, PDO::PARAM_STR );
                        $stmt_position->execute();
                        while ($row = $stmt_position->fetch()){ 
                        echo  "<dd>".$row['text']."</dd>";  
                            }
                        */    
                        }catch(PDOExeption $e){
                        echo $e->getMessage();
                        echo $con->errorInfo();
                            } 
                        /*    
                          echo"</dl>";
                        echo"</div>"; 

                return $success;  
                */
                echo"</div>";
                echo "</td>" ;
                echo "</tr>";
                }
                }catch(PDOExeption $e){
                echo $e->getMessage();
                echo $con->errorInfo();
                }
                return $success;
             }             
         }  




     public function getCarType() {
         /*
         $this->manufacturer_code = "00";
         $this->main_type = "03";
         $this->subtype_code = "05";
          */
         $success = false;
         try{
            $con = new PDO( DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS ); 
            $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM car_type WHERE manufacturer_code = :manufacturer_code AND main_type = :main_type AND subtype_code = :subtype_code LIMIT 1";
            $stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
            $stmt_cartype->bindValue( "manufacturer_code", $this->manufacturer_code, PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt_cartype->bindValue( "main_type", $this->main_type, PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt_cartype->bindValue( "subtype_code", $this->subtype_code, PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt_cartype->execute();
                while ($row = $stmt_cartype->fetch()){
                    echo $row['manufacturer'];
                    echo "&nbsp;";
                    echo $row['model'];
                    echo "&nbsp;";
                    echo $row['submodel'];
                }
                }catch(PDOExeption $e){
                echo $e->getMessage();
                echo $con->errorInfo();
                }

             return $success; 
         }               


 }
```

Comment: the code is not terrible, but your question is

Comment: Why, please be more specific, i have no problem to give more info or describe what i mean

Comment: Not all questions benefit from including code. But if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some. But don't just copy in your entire program! Not only is this likely to get you in trouble if you're posting your employer's code, it likely includes a lot of irrelevant details that readers will need to ignore when trying to reproduce the problem.[Here are some guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PDO in PDO issue in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26281665/pdo-in-pdo-issue-in-php)